# Trouble with body effect physics

Tags: mosfet, physics, device, solid-state-devices, field

I’m struggling to understand why a negative voltage applied to the bulk contact of an n-type MOSFET increases the threshold voltage.

I read other similar questions and I get that the negative voltage attracts holes, widening the depletion region under the gate which in turn makes it ‘harder’ for the gate to accumulate electrons.

So I have 2 questions:

1. Applying a negative voltage to the bulk makes the potential difference (and thus the field) between the gate and the bulk greater, which should make it easier to attract electrons under the gate. Why is this wrong?

And

2. Intuitively, the negative voltage at the bulk terminal repels electrons, pushing them towards the gate. Doesn’t this mean that the electron concentration under the gate increases more rapidly?

Comment: Crossposted to https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/711099/2451

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Answer at https://physics.stackexchange.com/a/711119/305176

Brief summary:

electrons to form the inversion layer come from the source, and with a negative bulk potential we are reverse biasing the source-bulk p-n junction, so we need more gate potential to get them out.

The mentioned effects aren’t wrong I think, they just aren’t relevant.